# Autosys: Change directory before executing job

Tags: autosys

I'm new to Autosys and I'm using the WCC front end in order to run autosys jobs. I also have access to the terminal if the answer proves to only work in the terminal

I was wondering how to change the directory before running a job. At the moment, Autosys searches its root directory for a batch file buit I want it to point to C:/scripts. IS there any way to define this as the starting directory or am i stuck leaving script files in the root directory of Autosys?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full path to the script should stand in the "command" section, e.g.:

```
insert_job: my_job job_type: c
command: C\:\Scripts\script1.bat
machine: appserver.domain.com
```

Alternative solution is to add C:\Scripts to the PATH variable on your app server.